# Paypal Express Checkout without amount

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

I am trying to set up to render the paypal express button on a donation page on my site. 
Is there a way to pass the information with an open amount, and the donor can put in their custom amount after their login to their paypal, or must I always include an amount. 
Or perhaps is there a different setting for a donation? 
My current code looks like this.

```
<script>
    paypal.Button.render({
        env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox',
         client: {
        sandbox:    'AZlk9a********eeMSKsOLLQbu',
        production: 'AeD266ReBO9**************7IfI-O8sJA'
    },
        commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button
 style: {
            color: 'gold',
            size: 'medium'
        },

         payment: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.create({
            payment: {
                transactions:  [
  {
    "amount": {
"total": "5",
"currency": "USD",

},
"description": "General Donation" ,

"invoice_number": "",
 }
]
            }
        });
    },
 onCancel: function(data, actions) {
       window.location = "https://www.****asp";

    },
       onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
   return actions.payment.get().then(function(data) {

            // Display the payment details and a confirmation button

          /***.......**///
                 // Execute the payment

              return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {

             $('form').submit();

                });
        });
    }
},
      '#paypal-button-container'); 
</script>
```

Comment: They will have to input their donation AMT prior to a paypal login session. An AMT field will not populate once logged in.[doesn't work like paypal buttons, where you can do this] That said, you cannot submit a $0 Express Checkout transaction as that's not supported with this method, only the PayPal Pro gateway can.

Comment: Is there any way to do a validation when the paypal button is checked ? I need to make sure the amount field is filled out before they submit